# ¿Cómo actualizar columnas omitiendo Foreign Keys?

Tags: sql-server

Mi problema es el siguiente:
1.- Tengo que modificar la longitud de varios campos en mi Base de Datos, el problema es que como tienen foreign keys por consiguiente no me deja realizar la acción de Alter Table ... Alter Column.

2.- Lo que hice fue obtener todas las foreign keys y eliminarlas después realizar el cambio de longitud de los campos, mi problema es que al agregar de nuevo las foreign keys truena debido a que son más de 1700 llaves foráneas que debe de agregar.

Si existe alguna forma de hacer la actualización de la longitud de los campos omitiendo las foreign keys se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

No tiene porqué darte error aunque sean muchas foreign keys.
La manera correcta de hacerlo es la que defines:

Eliminar las foreign keys

Modificar las columnas (y datos si es necesario)

Volver a crear las foreign keys

Mira este ejemplo. Creo dos tablas (Maestro y Detalle), Detalle tiene una Foreign Key a la Primary Key de la tabla Maestro. Los campos están definidos inicialmente como varchar(1) y los cambio a varchar(10) actualizando también los datos de éstos.

Por supuesto debes asegurarte de que los datos sean correctos antes de volver a crear la Foreign Key. Es decir, que no exista ningún valor en la tabla relacionada que no esté en la tabla principal.

```
-- Creación de las tablas
CREATE TABLE Maestro(
    [id] varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    [nombre] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Maestro] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE Detalle(
    [maestro_id] varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    [id] varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    [descripcion] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Detalle] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([maestro_id] ASC, [id] ASC)
)
-- Creación de la Foreign Key
ALTER TABLE Detalle WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Detalle_Maestro] FOREIGN KEY([maestro_id])
REFERENCES Maestro ([id])
ALTER TABLE Detalle CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Detalle_Maestro]

-- Insertar datos iniciales
INSERT INTO Maestro VALUES ('1', 'Maestro 1')
INSERT INTO Maestro VALUES ('2', 'Maestro 2')
INSERT INTO Maestro VALUES ('3', 'Maestro 3')
INSERT INTO Detalle VALUES ('1', '1', 'Línea Detalle 1_1')
INSERT INTO Detalle VALUES ('1', '2', 'Línea Detalle 1_2')
INSERT INTO Detalle VALUES ('2', '1', 'Línea Detalle 2_1')
INSERT INTO Detalle VALUES ('2', '2', 'Línea Detalle 2_2')
INSERT INTO Detalle VALUES ('3', '1', 'Línea Detalle 3_1')
INSERT INTO Detalle VALUES ('3', '2', 'Línea Detalle 3_2')

-- Eliminar Foreign Key
ALTER TABLE Detalle DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Detalle_Maestro]

-- Modificar Columnas
ALTER TABLE Maestro ALTER COLUMN id varchar(10) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE Detalle ALTER COLUMN maestro_id varchar(10) NOT NULL

-- Modificar los datos
UPDATE Maestro SET id='0000000001' WHERE id='1'
UPDATE Maestro SET id='0000000002' WHERE id='2'
UPDATE Maestro SET id='0000000003' WHERE id='3'
UPDATE Detalle SET maestro_id='0000000001' WHERE maestro_id='1'
UPDATE Detalle SET maestro_id='0000000002' WHERE maestro_id='2'
UPDATE Detalle SET maestro_id='0000000003' WHERE maestro_id='3'

-- Volver a crear Foreign Key
ALTER TABLE Detalle WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Detalle_Maestro] FOREIGN KEY([maestro_id])
REFERENCES Maestro ([id])
ALTER TABLE Detalle CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Detalle_Maestro]

-- Ver resultado
SELECT * FROM Maestro
SELECT * FROM Detalle

-- Eliminación de las tablas
DROP TABLE Detalle
DROP TABLE Maestro
```